# How do you exercise your hand before playing the piano?

Tags: piano

I'm kind of getting tired of strickly going up and down with scales
Is there any methods I should try ?

Answer (score 1):

Some activities include:

- arpeggios
- octaves
- chromatic (technically a scale but different from maj/min)
- polyrhythms
- Etudes (at higher levels, this may become a great warmup)

It would be beneficial to learn contrasting etudes eg. (vivace and adagio tempo contrast or cantabile and staccato contrast).

Mind you, these are only suggestions but if you feel any pain in your hands, rest and seek medical help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you don't play more than 4 hours a day (straight way) there's no reason to exercise your hand first, in fact during a hanon section you are already exercising your finger you won't need a kind of preparation exercises.